# Multi level category in multiselect of CodeIgniter with single table

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am trying to create a multi level category from $form->multiselect().

Below is my table  structure.

```
| id | parent |  name   |
|----|--------|---------|
| 10 |      0 | 'menu1' |
| 12 |     10 | 'menu2' |
| 13 |     10 | 'menu3' |
| 14 |      0 | 'menu4' |
```

The result is

```
+----+---------+
| id |  name   |
+----+---------+
| 10 | 'menu1' |
| 12 | 'menu2' |
| 13 | 'menu3' |
| 14 | 'menu4' |
+----+---------+
```

the id showed for value and name for  display in select element.

```
<select>
  <option value='10'>menu1</option>
  <option value='12'>menu2</option>
  <option value='13'>menu3</option>
  <option value='14'>menu4</option>
</select>
```

not showed Hierarchy .I want to show below.

```
<select>
      <option value='10'>menu1</option>
      <option value='12'>menu1 -> menu2</option>
      <option value='13'>menu1 -> menu3</option>
      <option value='14'>menu4</option>
    </select>
```

What should I do?

I would like to manipulated the structure of $form_multiselect().

Comment: You will have to create your own custom helper for this.

Comment: Is the table in a database?

Comment: Yes.first schema on top page.{code added into block}

Comment: please check this  [Dynamic Multi-level CSS Menu with PHP and MySQL](http://wizardinternetsolutions.com/articles/web-programming/dynamic-multilevel-css-menu-php-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the table you listed at the top is in a database by the format you got it in... If this is how you are getting it try (you didn't post your table names so you'll have to do that yourself):

```
$result = $this->db->select('CASE WHEN b.name IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT(a.name, ,\' -> \' b.name) ELSE a.name END AS option')
    ->from('yourtable a')
    ->join('yourtable b', 'a.parent = b.id', 'left')
    ->get()->result();
```

If your question has mislead me, I apologise... Wasn't much to go on...

Comment: I use activerecord to get data

Comment: This should not be done at DB layer. What if leafs also will have another leafs. Could you imagine how big will this query with 10 levels of adjacencies? In most cases enough to get all rows and later make `foreach` and group these to array which looks like `$menu = ['parent' => 'menu1', 'child' => ['menu2', 'menu3', 'etc.']]`. This is most easiest way, another is use trees more smart but and more hard way in the same time. Please take a look into this blog post http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: In MySQL, sure. SQL Server which I use all the time, just build it with a recursive cte. At any rate... I've offered a solution, feel free to offer your own

Comment: Just a moment.try to use it.

Comment: Multi level category multiselect CodeIgniter
https://github.com/hamedhossani/Multi_level_category_multiselect_CodeIgniter