# How to assign,Multidimensional array to Bidimensional Array?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

How to assign , Multidimensional array to Bidimensional Array?
to show category Hierarchy  in drop down.($form_multiselect())

i have this table

```
| id | parent |  name   |
|----|--------|---------|
| 10 |      0 | 'menu1' |
| 12 |     10 | 'menu2' |
| 13 |     10 | 'menu3' |
| 14 |      0 | 'menu4' |
```

php code is.

```
function prepare_items($data_from_table_of_database,$parent){
    $items = array ();      
        foreach ( $data_from_table_of_database as $item ) {
            if ($item ['parent'] == $parent) {
                $items ['id'] = $item;
                $items ['id'] ['children'] = 
                    $this->prepare_items ( $data_from_table_of_database, $item ['id']);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have array code showed in below

```
Array (
     [107] => Array ( [id] => 107 [menu_title] => تست1 [parent] => 0 [sort_order] => 1 [children] => Array ( ) )
     [111] => Array ( [id] => 111 [menu_title] => تست 4 [parent] => 0 [sort_order] => 1 [children] => Array ( 
            [109] => Array ( [id] => 109 [menu_title] => تست 1 [parent] => 111 [sort_order] => 1 [children] => Array ( ) )
             [115] => Array ( [id] => 115 [menu_title] => تست7 [parent] => 111 [sort_order] => 1 [children] => Array ( [110] => Array ( [id] => 110 [menu_title] => تست 3 [parent] => 115 [sort_order] => 1 [children] => Array ( ) ) ) ) ) )
     [112] => Array ( [id] => 112 [menu_title] => تست 4 [parent] => 0 [sort_order] => 1 [children] => Array ( ) ) 
     [113] => Array ( [id] => 113 [menu_title] => تست 5 [parent] => 0 [sort_order] => 1 [children] => Array ( ) ) 
     [114] => Array ( [id] => 114 [menu_title] => تست شش6 [parent] => 0 [sort_order] => 3 [children] => Array ( 
            [108] => Array ( [id] => 108 [menu_title] => تست 2 [parent] => 114 [sort_order] => 1 [children] => Array ( ) ) 
     [118] => Array ( [id] => 118 [menu_title] => yeeeeeee [parent] => 114 [sort_order] => 1 [children] => Array ( ) ) ) ) 
     [119] => Array ( [id] => 119 [menu_title] => ff [parent] => 0 [sort_order] => 1 [children] => Array (
             [117] => Array ( [id] => 117 [menu_title] => shar [parent] => 119 [sort_order] => 1 [children] => Array ( ) ) ) )
     )
```

i will add to another array same structure bellow

```
Array (
     [107] => Array ( [id] => 107 [menu_title] => تست1  [sort_order] => 2 )
     [111] => Array ( [id] => 111 [menu_title] => تست 4  [sort_order] => 3 )
     [109] => Array ( [id] => 109 [menu_title] => تست 4 -- تست 1  [sort_order] => 1 )
     [115] => Array ( [id] => 115 [menu_title] =>  تست 4 -- تست7  [sort_order] => 1 )
     [110] => Array ( [id] => 110 [menu_title] => تست 4 -- تست7 -- تست 3   [sort_order] => 1)
     .
     .
     .

     )
```

I Ask the Another Question Yesterday Related this Subject.

[that's link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42267593/multi-level-category-in-multiselect-of-codeigniter-with-single-table)

I am trying to create a multi level category from $form->multiselect().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer.

```
private  function build_item(&$list,$item,$level,$element_keys){
        $list[$item[$element_keys['menu_id']]]=str_repeat(" -> ", $level). $item[$element_keys['menu_title']];  
    }

private  function build_item_list($items,$element_keys ,$element_keys,$level=0) {

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {       
        $this->build_item($this->list,$item,$level,$element_keys);

            if(count($item['children'])>0){
                $this->build_item_list($item['children'],$element_keys,$element_keys,++$level);
            }
    }
    return  ( $this->list );
    }
```

It's Generate array below

```
 [1] => Array ( [107] => تست1 ) 
 [2] => Array ( [111] => تست 4 )
 [3] => Array ( [109] => -> تست 1 ) 
 [4] => Array ( [115] => -> تست7 ) 
 [5] => Array ( [110] => -> -> تست 3 ) 
 [6] => Array ( [112] => -> تست 4 ) 
 [7] => Array ( [113] => -> تست 5 )
 [8] => Array ( [114] => -> تست شش6 )
 [9] => Array ( [108] => -> -> تست 2 )
```

It's my paradise.

Comment: multi level category/menu for codeigniter
https://github.com/hamedhossani/Multi_level_category_multiselect_CodeIgniter